# Create ranges of different lengths in R using for and while loops

Tags: r, for-loop, while-loop

I want to make a loop in R that as a result saves a range whose minimum size is 1000 (initial binLength) and increases its size by 10 points (stepSize) each time the condition is not met. I send the script that I have but I am not getting the result I want.

```
set.seed(123)

newbins = seq(0,5000,1000)
binLength = 1000
stepSize = 10
blocks=NULL
end = 0


for (b in newbins[1:length(newbins)-1]){
  tempBP = 0
  tempBP_new = 0
  start = end +1
  end = binLength
  while (sum(tempBP_new-tempBP) < 0.40){
    tempBP_new = tempBP
    tempBP_new = runif(1)*0.5
    binLength = binLength + stepSize
    blocks = rbind(blocks,c(start, end))
  }
}
blocks
```

The output of the script is:

```
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1 1000
 [2,]    1 1000
 [3,]    1 1000
 [4,]    1 1000
 [5,] 1001 1040
 [6,] 1041 1050
 [7,] 1041 1050
 [8,] 1041 1050
 [9,] 1051 1080
[10,] 1051 1080
[11,] 1051 1080
[12,] 1081 1110
[13,] 1081 1110
[14,] 1081 1110
[15,] 1081 1110
[16,] 1081 1110
```

But I want something like for example

```
   1 1000
1001 2040
2041 3050
3050 5000
```

In other words, each range must be at least 1000 and the loop has to end when it reaches 5000. I also don't understand why I have the same result several times in the loop. Do you have any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified the end of the interval at each iteration and not your minimal length which should remain constant. I also simplified your code by removing useless lists or function calls.
The reason you obtain the same results is because you increment your table in the while loop and not when it is finished.
Also, I don't know if you want the start or the end of the interval to be below 5000. Regardless this should be relatively easy to fix from there.

```
set.seed(123)

binLength = 1000
stepSize = 10
blocks = NULL
end = 0

while (end + 1 < 5000){
  tempBP = 0
  tempBP_new = 0
  start = end + 1
  end = end + binLength
  while (tempBP_new - tempBP < 0.40){
    tempBP_new = tempBP
    tempBP = runif(1) * 0.5
    end = end + stepSize
    }
  blocks = rbind(blocks, c(start, min(5000, end)))
  }
blocks
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1 1060
[2,] 1061 2510
[3,] 2511 4270
[4,] 4271 5000
```

Edit: According to the comments, I modified the code to prevent the end of interval to exceed 5000.

Comment: Hi Marc, it is quite similar to what I need, I need the last number to be 5000. So I will have to modify it a bit because now it is 6720, but otherwise, it looks good!

Comment: Ok. Also, keep in mind that with this implementation, the bin lengths will be 1010 at least, since the while loop is always entered once at least because tempBP and tempBP_new are set to 0. If you really want bins of 1000 at least, you could set the binLength to 990 (1000 - 10)

Comment: I am having trouble setting the maximum value as 5000, do you have any idea how to do it? Thank you!!

Comment: Is it what you expect?

Comment: Exactly! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what your output should be despite you wrote it.

But if you delete the seed you would see that the output of your vector is strongly dependent of the runif function, thus you dont get a fixed result, if that is of your concern.

In addition, when using the browser() function you would see that in every step the value of tempBP_new is under 0.40 by random, thus you generate more than one occurence of:
1 1000 everytime because that is also dependent by runif. Your loop does not know when the temperature will be exceeded and you "rbind" your result in the while loop.

And binding something ina loop which endiing or next move is determined by random will create different ranges

And you are not increasing binLength = binLength + stepSize by thousand, you are only increasing the StepSize.

Is this something more like you wanted it?

```
    newbins = seq(0,5000,1000)
    binLength = 1000
    stepSize = 10
    blocks=NULL
    end = 1000
    seq_2 <- seq(0, 5, 1)
    start = 1
    
    
    
    for (b in seq_2){
      if (end >= 5000)
         break
      
      tempBP = 0
      tempBP_new = 0
      while (sum(tempBP_new-tempBP) < 0.40){
        tempBP_new = tempBP
        tempBP_new = runif(1)*0.5
        
      }
      blocks = rbind(blocks,c(start, end))
      start = start + binLength + stepSize
      end = binLength+start-1 + (stepSize*b)
    }
    blocks
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1 1000
[2,] 1011 2010
[3,] 2021 3030
[4,] 3031 4050
```

Comment: Hi Patrick, thanks for your help. Yes I know this is dependent on the runif, in fact in that place I have to add a function but I wrote in that way for the example to make it easy to reproduce. But I am closer now to what I need. :) thanks!

Comment: You are welcome! Keep up your work and a good weekend to you!